# Every open interval has an open subinterval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, logic, proof-writing

I want to prove the following propsotion:

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. If $b\in I$, there exist $a$ and $c$ in I with $a < b < c$.

I think that we should give a proof by contradiction:

My first attempt is:

The proposition can be written in the language of symbolic logic,

$\forall~ b\in I~~~~ \exists~ a,c\in I~~~~a<b<c$

The opposite of this statement is:

$\exists~ b\in I~~~~ \forall~ a,c\in I~~~~(a\geq b)\vee (b\geq c)$

How can i find a contradiction from here?

My second attempt is:

Let $I=(m,n)$. The following propositions are true:

$\forall~ b\in I~~~~ \exists~ \epsilon>0~~~~b>n-\epsilon$

and

$\forall~ b\in I~~~~ \exists~ \delta>0~~~~b<m+\delta$

Therefore, if we choose $a=n-\epsilon$ and $c=m+\delta$, we find $a<b<c$. But i can't show $n-\epsilon\in I$ and $m+\delta\in I$.

Comment: Perhaps you also wish to show that $a,c\in I?$

Comment: This follows trivially from the fact that an open interval has neither a least member nor a greatest member. In other words the thing you want to prove is a definition of an open interval.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I try to write this fact formally.

Comment: You did not get my point. Definitions are not proved. They are taken as basis to prove various properties about the things which have been defined.

Comment: I think that this is not a definition.

Comment: How do you define an open interval?

Comment: I want to say that "an open interval has neither a least member nor a greatest member" is a proposition not definition so it can be proved.

Comment: In that case it is even more important that you define the term "open interval" in some other manner without using least/greatest member idea. And if you have one such definition do provide it. And then one has to begin with that definition and prove the proposition you state. The accepted answer here use the definition based on least member and greatest member and thus does not constitute a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $\exists~ b\in I~~\forall~ a,c\in I:~~ (a\geq b)\lor (c\leq b)$. Then, self-evidentally, $$\exists~ b\in I~~\forall~ a,c\in I\setminus \left\{ {b}\right\}:~~ (a> b)\lor (c<b).$$But because $a,c \in I\setminus \left\{ {b}\right\}$ is symmetric, it also follows that $$\exists~ b\in I~~\forall~ a,c\in I\setminus \left\{ {b}\right\}:~~ (a<b)\lor (c>b).$$ In order for both statements to hold, it must be $$\exists~ b\in I~~\forall~ a,c\in I\setminus \left\{ {b}\right\}:~~ (a,c>b)\lor (a,c<b).$$ Now if there were for all $b\in I$ two pairs $(a',c'), (a'',c'')\in I^2$ with $a',c'>b$ but $a'',c''<b$, then $a=a'',c=a'$ would contradict our assumption. Therefore, $$\exists~ b\in I:~~(\forall~ a,c\in I\setminus \left\{ {b}\right\}:~~ a,c>b)~\lor~(\forall~a,c\in I\setminus \left\{ {b}\right\}:~~ a,c<b).$$ But this would mean that $b$ is the minimum or the maximum of $I$ contradicting the fact that an open interval has neither a minimum nor a maximum. Therefore, our assumption from the beginning must be false and the claim must hold.

However, if you want a shorter proof, you could just take $a=b-\frac{b-m}{2}, c=b+\frac{n-b}{2}$ where $I=(m,n)$ and then prove quite easily that $m<a<b<c<n$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What do you think about my second attempt?

Comment: Well, in a way, my second proof is your second approach with $\epsilon =n-\frac{b}{2} - \frac{m}{2} $ and $\delta = \frac{b}{2} + \frac{n}{2} - m $ so by choosing $\epsilon , \delta $ carefully, your approach can definitely work. However, I am not sure if you can also finish up your proof like this without choosing a specific value for $\epsilon ,\delta $.